# Tomcat 8 / MySql Integration issue

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I have an issue with mySql integration into Tomcat 8. I will detail my steps and the error that occurs below.

1. I have added the connector jar to catalina_home/lib
2. I have created a brand new database called testdb, and created a new web project called TCmySqlSetup
3. In Meta-inf/context.xml I added:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/TCmySqlSetup">    
    <Resource name="jdbc/testdb"
    auth="Container"    
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"    
    username="root"    
    password="myPass"    
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"    
    url="jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/testdb"    
    maxActive="15"    
    maxIdle="3"/>    
</Context>
```

4. Then I created web.xml

```
 <web-app>     
 <resource-ref>     
 <description>Db Conn</description>     
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/testdb</res-ref-name>     
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>     
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>     
 </resource-ref>     
 </web-app>
```

5. Inside my index.JSP I have placed

```
 // InitialContext ctx =null;
 DataSource ds =null;
 Statement stmt= null;
 Connection con = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 // try{ Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
 /* ctx = new InitialContext();
 ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/testdb");*/

 Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
 Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
 ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/testdb");

 con = ds.getConnection();
 stmt = con.createStatement();
```

I havent copied the whole code, because the problem doesnt lie there, it's just simple column extraction...

And then when I try to run the website I get this:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
JSP page /index.jsp at line 47

44: 45: 46: 47: 
con = ds.getConnection(); 48: stmt =
con.createStatement(); 49: 50: rs =
stmt.executeQuery("select name from employee");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create
JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL
'jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/MySQL56'
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:223)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class
'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL
'jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/MySQL56'
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2160)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:164)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2151)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2032)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:164)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have been fighting with this for a long period of time and i really want to do it right, i have most of the code for my real environment and it seems that i can connect without pooling somehow with this code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

 java.sql.Connection conn;

 conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb","root","peskir123");
 Statement sqlStatement = conn.createStatement();
```

Comment: Despite your claim to have added the JAR, the exception message says it can't find the class. That's pretty explicit, so I don't know how else to answer this question. You could try adding a different JAR to the `lib` directory (literally any JAR) and confirm that an application deployed to Tomcat can load a class from that JAR...

Comment: I think I misunderstood. You're saying that last snippet of code works to load the driver: "it seems that i can connect without pooling somehow with this code..." What happens if in your JSP you include the line that says `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()`? This should load the driver.

Comment: Thats why i can't get it, when i use Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance() it still can not find the driver if i am using the pooling method(It is just commented on the top so there is no confusion). i believe that that behavior is quite unusual... Any suggestion would help me, i am out of ideas. :D

Comment: Try replacing `url="jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/testdb"` to `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"` with `//` in context.xml.

Comment: I can not belive it, it worked....... Thank you so much!!!!!